# chain_provider and Authentication Provider

Tags: ldap, forms-authentication, symfony

When using the chain_provider with Doctrine and a custom User Provider, is it suppose to use the provider's Authentication Provider also?

I got an issue with using a custom User Provider in the chain_provider, as described below :

```
providers:
    chain_provider:
        providers: [doctrine, egzakt_backend_ldap]
    doctrine:
        entity: { class: Egzakt\Backend\UserBundle\Entity\User }
    egzakt_backend_ldap:
        id: egzakt_backend_ldap.security.user.provider

firewalls:
   secured_area:
        pattern: /admin/
        form_login:
            provider: chain_provider
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            login_path: /admin/login
```

The problem is that egzakt_backend_ldap User Provider is called correctly, but not by the good Authentication Provider. Instead of be called by "LdapAuthenticationProvider", which I declared as a service in my factory, it is called by "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\ProviderDaoAuthenticationProvide‌​r" and always return a "The presented password is invalid" because it's not using the good Authentication Provider to validate the credentials.

BUT, if using the entry point directly, it's working. The problem is that I want to use BOTH Doctrine and Ldap to login, if Doctrine fails, it falls back to Ldap :

```
firewalls:
   secured_area:
        pattern: /admin/
        egzakt_backend_ldap:
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            login_path: /admin/login
```

With this way, it uses the good Authentication Provider and User Provider.

Anyone has an idea about what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `providers` section of config to this:

```
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [doctrine, egzakt_backend_ldap]
doctrine:
    entity: { class: Egzakt\Backend\UserBundle\Entity\User }
egzakt_backend_ldap:
    id: egzakt_backend_ldap.security.user.provider
```

You missed the `chain` key, the `chain_provider` is just a name.